# Perl Object Hierarchy introspection

Tags: perl, oop, package

Lets say I have the following package Hierarchy:

```
A--> B --> C --> D
```

Which means `A` is the base class and `B` inherits from it in turn `C` inherits from B and so on.

also, lets say I have the following line of code:

```
my $co = D->new();
```

is there any way to check (some `UNIVERSAL` method?) if object `co` is is a descendant of `A` ? (or in general, to test if an object `X` is a descendant of package `P`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [UNIVERSAL](http://p3rl.org/UNIVERSAL).

```
if ($D->isa('A')) {print "do something fancy"}
```

or

```
if ($D->can('method_defined_in_A')) {print "can do that";}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `can`. Using `isa` usually means you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use

```
$co->isa($package_name);
```

its a UNIVERSAL method that all perl blessed references have.
http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html